# nodejs Async : concurency worker push the same task again in the queue

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, concurrency

I was wondering what is the best way to push a new task again in the queue indefinitely after it finished using the async module for nodejs ?

```
var q = async.queue(function (task, callback) {
    console.log('hello ' + task.name);
    doSomeFunction(task.name, function(cb){
        callback();
    });
}, 2);

q.drain = function() {
    console.log('all items have been processed');
}

// add some items to the queue
for (var i in list) {
    q.push({name: i}, function (err) {
       console.log('finished task');
       //***HERE I would like to push indefinitely this task in the queue again
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do a recursive function.

```
for (var i in list) {
   //Put inside an anonymous function to keep the current value of i
   (function(item) {
     var a=function(item){
       q.push({name: item}, function (err) {
          console.log('finished task');
          //call the function again
          a(item)
       });
     }
     a(item)
   })(i);
}
```

This cod will add indefinitely all the tasks in the queue, one by one (when a task is finished, than the same task is added in queue).

Btw...You didn't call the callback in worker function

```
var q = async.queue(function (task, callback) {
   console.log('hello ' + task.name);
   //You have to call the callback
   //You have 2 options: 
   doSomeFunction(task.name,callback); //option 1 -> doSomeFunction - asynchronous function 
   //doSomeFunction(task.name);callback(); //option 2 doSomeFunction - synchronous function 
}, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, gonna try this! I was going for another solution before you answered.. Calling a function in the `q.drain` that parses my `list` array again and push the tasks in queue. Don't know which one is really the best.. Any idea ? Btw. thank you for the callback, I forgot it

Comment: Your approach is not so efficient. For example, if in your list there are 3 elements(1,2,3) and you have 2 workers, than the flow will be: do in parallel 1&2 ; do 3; put again elements in queue; do in parallel 1&2; do 3 and so on;  The flow for my approach is do in parallel 1& 2; do in parallel 3 & 1; and so on.